# Eigenvalue analysis, subject to boundary conditions

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nonlinear-optimization

For some non-linear finite element program I have a Tangent stiffness matrix $\textbf{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, which is symmetric. I want to find the Eigenvector corresponding to the smallest Eigenvalue of this matrix, such that each component of this Eigenvector is non-negative. I know the smallest Eigenpair can be found via different methods (e.g. Inverste iterative method, or Rayleigh quotient iteration, Lanczos method etc.). But, is there a method to extract the smallest Eigenpair of the tangent stiffness matrix, such that all the components of the Eigenvector are non-negative? Is this even possible?

Comment: The Perron-Frobenius theorem is one tool to guarantee positive eigenvectors. However they correspond to the largest eigenvalue of the matrix. You could maybe consider $K^{-1}$. The theorem also states that the eigenvalue is simple, so any eigenvector you compute will have either negative or positive components.

The matrix need to have positive entries, I don't know if that's the case for you.

Comment: In my case it is not guaranteed that the matrix has positive entries. Is there any option to guarantee non-negative eigenvectors without the property that the matrix is positive?

Comment: Moreover, because of non-linearity I have $\textbf{K} = \textbf{K}(\textbf{x})$, i.e. the tangent stiffness matrix depends on the Eigenvector